# how do I change the value of int to be the result of a looping equation?

Tags: java

New to Java. I have to create a hailstone sequence and after 5 hours of headache I'm completely lost.
Basically, I need to take the user's number and run it through an equation that changes depending on whether the number is even or odd. I then need to take the result and run it again until the end result =1.

What I can't figure out is how to get the program to use the result of the previous calculation to do the next one in the loop.

example:

```
int x = readInt("Enter a number: ");
    int xEven = (x/2);
    int xOdd = (x*3+1);
    int counter = 0;
    
    public void run()
    {
        while(x != 1)
        {
            if(x % 2 == 0)
            {
                println(x + " is even, so I take half: " + xEven);
            }
            else
            {
                println(x + " is odd, so i make 3x + 1: " + xOdd);
            }
            counter++;
        }
        println("The process took " + counter + " steps to reach 1.");
    }
```

The result should look like this:

```
Enter a number: 17
17 is odd, so I make 3x + 1: 52
52 is even, so I take half: 26
26 is even, so I take half: 13
13 is odd, so I make 3x + 1: 40
40 is even, so I take half: 20
20 is even, so I take half: 10
10 is even, so I take half: 5
5 is odd, so I make 3x + 1: 16
16 is even, so I take half: 8
8 is even, so I take half: 4
4 is even, so I take half: 2
2 is even, so I take half: 1
The process took 12 steps to reach 1.
```

When I run my code it just repeats the first input forever without looping so it looks like this:

```
17 is odd, so I make 3x + 1: 52
17 is odd, so I make 3x + 1: 52
17 is odd, so I make 3x + 1: 52
17 is odd, so I make 3x + 1: 52
17 is odd, so I make 3x + 1: 52
17 is odd, so I make 3x + 1: 52
etc...
```

Comment: You never change `x`. You should change at the place where you print and *claim* to *make* it.

Comment: You don't need `xEven` and `xOdd`. You never change their value, or the value of `x`. Therefore, it's normal that you see the same output repeated. You already have a loop, do your calculations there, not right after you take the input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int steps = 0;

    while (x != 1) {
        if (x % 2 == 0)
            System.out.format("%d is even, so I take half: %d\n", x, x /= 2);
        else
            System.out.format("%d is odd, so I make 3x + 1: %d\n", x, x = 3 * x + 1);

        steps++;
    }

    System.out.format("The process took %d steps to reach 1.", steps);
}
```

Comment: While I appreciate your response, I don't understand most of it as I am very new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the new value to your variable `x`.
For instance do `x = xEven;` or `x = xOdd` right after the prints.
Also you will need to move the computation of `xEven` and `xOdd` inside the while loop.

PS: There are a few possible ways to reduce your code.

Feel free to ask if you need more explanations.

Comment: I placed x= xEven inside the loop and I get an error "cannot find symbol" for x

Comment: Well, not too sure what is the problem but maybe you forgot a `;` or have a syntax error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  Just make the following changes indicated by comments. But first, remove your earlier declarations of `xEven` and `xOdd`

```
        while (x != 1) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                x = x / 2;                   //add
                int xEven = x;               //add
                System.out.println(
                        x + " is even, so I take half: " + xEven);
            } else {
                x = x * 3 + 1;               //add
                int xOdd = x;                //add
                System.out.println(
                        x + " is odd, so i make 3x + 1: " + xOdd);
            }
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println(
                "The process took " + counter + " steps to reach 1.");
```

I also added `System.out` to `println`.  If you are using a different package then you may not need to change it.

Comment: Oh 

man, that's really close. Now it looks like this:

```
Enter a number: 25
76 is odd, so i make 3n + 1: 76
38 is even, so I take half: 38
19 is even, so I take half: 19
```
I should be able to figure it out from here on my own so thanks.

Comment: I think the XEven and XOdd assignments should be moved up one statement before `x` is updated.  But it depends on the nature of the messages your are printing.